# Is R with finite complement top path-connected?

Tags: general-topology

I need to prove whether $\mathbb R$ with the finite complement topology is path-connected or not.

Is the following proof valid?

The function $ g:(\mathbb R,u) \rightarrow (\mathbb R,fc) $ is continuous.

Because $\mathbb R_u$ is path-connected, any path from a to b is given by the continuous function

$f:I \rightarrow [a, b]$.

Thus their composition
$g\circ f:(I,u)\rightarrow([a,b], fc)$ is continuous, proving that $\mathbb R$ endowed with the finite complement topology is path-connected.

Comment: Assuming that by $u$ you mean the “usual” (Euclidean?) topology, this is imho exactly the right way to prove this.

Answer (score 2):

For a space X to be path connected, there should exist a continuous function from [0,1] to X such that, $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$, for all $x, y$ in X. So for your proof to hold true, the function $g∘f$ needs to have the above mentioned property. I think the function $f:[0,1]→(R,fc)$ that works is $f(t)=tx + (1-t)y$, for $x,y$ in X. The inverse image of a closed set is closed for this function as the only closed sets in finite complement topology are finite sets, and inverse image of finite sets is a finite set in R with usual topology which is closed. 
Hope this helps.